# Joining results from one query to another table

Tags: inner-join

How can I combine this:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) AS `rank` FROM `rtgitems` ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
```

with this?

```
INNER JOIN vouchers ON vouchers.item = rtgitems.item
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concat it into a single query:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT rtgitems.item, (totalrate / nrrates) AS rank
                            FROM rtgitems 
                            INNER JOIN vouchers ON vouchers.item = rtgitems.item 
                            ORDER BY (totalrate / nrrates) 
                            DESC LIMIT 5") 
               or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks.  When I try that I get this error:  #1052 - Column 'item' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @MKJ Change item to rtgitems.item or vouchers.item in your select statement so that DB could know what item to select

Comment: It has kinda worked but I don't seem to have access to the data held in the vouchers table?

Comment: You should post another question :)